Kubuntu randomly freeze and graphic prossesor stay llvmpipe after upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04lts
my Laptop is Thinkpad L14 gen3 Intel(Engineering Sample) with i7-1260P.
After upgrading kubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04lts, the system freeze randomly happened, and the graphic processors shows llvmpipe instead of Intel Mesa UDH Graphic.(It must be some connections I believe). I`ve searched many method to repair but no one take effects.

What I`ve tired


Change /etc/default/grub.conf, not work
Reinstall Intel i915 driver and mesa-utils
Change mesa and libgl etc. with Intel version(https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/index.html) and oibaf version(https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/noble/), not work
Change kernel from 6.8.0-31-generic to 6.8.0-35-generic to self-compiled 6.8.3 to 6.9.1 to 6.10.0-rc2. Not work.
Change some xorg settings to force using intel driver and so on, not work.
Change /etc/modprobe.d/ to disable i915 driver or xe driver, not work.


Some other things I`ve Checked or found


Ive checked ``dmesg|grep i915``, the only error is GuC. But I think its ok to have this message because it always shown before upgrade and at that time everything runs normally.
After a freeze, I use a liveCD to runjournalctl --file system.journalanduser-1000.journal and there`s nothing suspected. The log just "broken" at the time freezed.
The liveCD burned in my USB drive sometimes orcurred freeze. May it be some hardwares fault?


Logs and confs


uname -a

Linux KUbuntu-ThinkPad 6.10.0-rc2 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jun  6 15:58:23 CST 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


/var/log/Xorg.0.log

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PXNWmxPdHt/

dmesg|grep i915(This is logs before I disabled i915 var blacklist)

[    6.969660] i915 0000:00:02.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    6.971011] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    6.992454] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    6.992525] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    6.993168] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=mem
[    6.996126] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/adlp_dmc.bin (v2.20)
[    7.112168] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_70.bin version 70.20.0
[    7.112173] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin version 7.9.3
[    7.114669] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: load failed: status = 0x800007EC, time = 0ms, freq = 1050MHz, ret = 0
[    7.114678] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: load failed: status: Reset = 0, BootROM = 0x76, UKernel = 0x07, MIA = 0x00, Auth = 0x02
[    7.114747] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: GuC initialization failed -ENXIO
[    7.114752] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: Enabling uc failed (-5)
[    7.114755] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: Failed to initialize GPU, declaring it wedged!
[    7.116121] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm:add_taint_for_CI [i915]] CI tainted:0x9 by intel_gt_set_wedged_on_init+0x34/0x50 [i915]
[    7.174790] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
[    7.197416] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    7.234538] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    7.234547] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    7.234390] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])


lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
f2fs                  962560  1
crc32_generic          12288  0
lz4hc_compress         20480  1 f2fs
lz4_compress           24576  1 f2fs
veth                   45056  0
xt_nat                 12288  9
xt_tcpudp              16384  0
xt_conntrack           12288  2
nft_chain_nat          12288  7
xt_MASQUERADE          16384  3
nf_nat                 61440  3 xt_nat,nft_chain_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    57344  0
nf_conntrack          188416  5 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,xt_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         12288  1 nf_conntrack
xfrm_user              57344  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            12288  2
nft_compat             20480  16
nf_tables             368640  196 nft_compat,nft_chain_nat
br_netfilter           32768  0
bridge                405504  1 br_netfilter
stp                    12288  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
ccm                    24576  6
rfcomm                 94208  16
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
snd_seq_midi           24576  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            57344  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq               114688  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
overlay               208896  2
cmac                   12288  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         12288  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
qrtr                   49152  2
bnep                   32768  2
binfmt_misc            24576  1
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl    12288  0
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    20480  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_intel_hda_generic    36864  2 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
iwlmvm                876544  0
nls_iso8859_1          12288  1
soundwire_intel        73728  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
intel_uncore_frequency    16384  0
intel_uncore_frequency_common    16384  1 intel_uncore_frequency
intel_tcc_cooling      12288  0
xe                   2801664  0
soundwire_cadence      40960  1 soundwire_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   180224  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_generic,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink    40960  3 soundwire_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda      24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
intel_powerclamp       24576  0
snd_sof_pci            24576  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_generic,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
mac80211             1699840  1 iwlmvm
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     12288  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
snd_sof               376832  5 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic,snd_sof_intel_hda,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_utils          16384  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match   106496  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_generic,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
soundwire_generic_allocation    12288  1 soundwire_intel
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
soundwire_bus         110592  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_avs           192512  0
coretemp               24576  0
snd_soc_hda_codec      24576  1 snd_soc_avs
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  6 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink,snd_sof_intel_hda
kvm_intel             471040  0
snd_soc_core          425984  6 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           28672  2 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               12288  1 snd_soc_core
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
kvm                  1388544  1 kvm_intel
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
cmdlinepart            12288  0
snd_hda_intel          61440  0
spi_nor               159744  0
uvcvideo              135168  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       45056  5 snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
iwlwifi               606208  1 iwlmvm
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  2 snd_intel_dspcfg,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
snd_hda_codec         204800  5 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
mtd                    98304  3 spi_nor,cmdlinepart
uvc                    12288  1 uvcvideo
ee1004                 16384  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_core          139264  8 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
mei_pxp                16384  0
mei_hdcp               28672  0
btusb                  77824  0
drm_gpuvm              40960  1 xe
btrtl                  32768  1 btusb
drm_exec               12288  2 drm_gpuvm,xe
videodev              352256  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
gpu_sched              61440  1 xe
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
btintel                61440  1 btusb
snd_pcm               192512  11 snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
drm_buddy              20480  1 xe
i2c_i801               36864  0
btmtk                  12288  1 btusb
videobuf2_common       86016  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
drm_suballoc_helper    20480  1 xe
rapl                   20480  0
drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 xe
i2c_mux                12288  1 i2c_i801
spi_intel_pci          12288  0
bluetooth            1003520  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
think_lmi              45056  0
processor_thermal_device_pci    16384  0
cfg80211             1318912  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
intel_cstate           24576  0
firmware_attributes_class    12288  1 think_lmi
wmi_bmof               12288  0
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
mc                     81920  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
spi_intel              32768  1 spi_intel_pci
i2c_smbus              16384  1 i2c_i801
ttm                   106496  2 drm_ttm_helper,xe
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
mei_me                 53248  2
nxp_nci_i2c            16384  0
processor_thermal_device    20480  1 processor_thermal_device_pci
drm_display_helper    253952  1 xe
mei                   172032  5 mei_hdcp,mei_pxp,mei_me
nxp_nci                12288  1 nxp_nci_i2c
processor_thermal_wt_hint    16384  2 processor_thermal_device_pci,processor_thermal_device
processor_thermal_rfim    32768  1 processor_thermal_device
cec                    94208  1 xe
nci                    86016  2 nxp_nci,nxp_nci_i2c
processor_thermal_rapl    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_pmc_core        118784  0
rc_core                73728  1 cec
intel_rapl_common      49152  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_rapl
nfc                   147456  2 nci,nxp_nci
processor_thermal_wt_req    12288  1 processor_thermal_device
thinkpad_acpi         159744  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 xe
intel_vsec             20480  1 intel_pmc_core
processor_thermal_power_floor    12288  2 processor_thermal_device_pci,processor_thermal_device
int3400_thermal        24576  0
pmt_telemetry          16384  1 intel_pmc_core
igen6_edac             24576  0
processor_thermal_mbox    12288  4 processor_thermal_power_floor,processor_thermal_wt_req,processor_thermal_rfim,processor_thermal_wt_hint
int3403_thermal        16384  0
intel_hid              28672  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
pmt_class              12288  1 pmt_telemetry
soc_button_array       20480  0
input_leds             12288  0
acpi_thermal_rel       20480  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_tad               20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
joydev                 32768  0
mac_hid                12288  0
serio_raw              20480  0
msr                    12288  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
parport                73728  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
efi_pstore             12288  0
nfnetlink              20480  5 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
dmi_sysfs              24576  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               65536  7 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_nat,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE
autofs4                57344  2
btrfs                1998848  1
blake2b_generic        24576  0
xor                    20480  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              126976  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12288  4 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,nf_tables
usbhid                 77824  0
mmc_block              61440  1
hid_multitouch         32768  0
hid_generic            12288  0
crct10dif_pclmul       12288  1
thunderbolt           516096  0
e1000e                348160  0
crc32_pclmul           12288  1
nvme                   61440  3
snd                   139264  15 snd_ctl_led,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
polyval_clmulni        12288  0
psmouse               204800  0
polyval_generic        12288  1 polyval_clmulni
sdhci_pci              86016  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
nvme_core             212992  4 nvme
sha256_ssse3           32768  0
ucsi_acpi              12288  0
sha1_ssse3             32768  0
i2c_hid_acpi           12288  0
cqhci                  40960  1 sdhci_pci
typec_ucsi             61440  1 ucsi_acpi
i2c_hid                40960  1 i2c_hid_acpi
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd
intel_lpss_pci         24576  0
sdhci                  90112  1 sdhci_pci
video                  73728  2 thinkpad_acpi,xe
hid                   262144  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
intel_lpss             12288  1 intel_lpss_pci
typec                 110592  1 typec_ucsi
xhci_pci               24576  0
idma64                 20480  0
nvme_auth              28672  1 nvme_core
xhci_pci_renesas       16384  1 xhci_pci
sparse_keymap          12288  2 intel_hid,thinkpad_acpi
platform_profile       12288  1 thinkpad_acpi
wmi                    28672  3 video,wmi_bmof,think_lmi
pinctrl_tigerlake      28672  3
aesni_intel           356352  8
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel

4.glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: -1.1.8
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 15728MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 31 MB, largest block: 31 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 12673 MB, largest block: 12673 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 31 MB, largest block: 31 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 12673 MB, largest block: 12673 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 31 MB, largest block: 31 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 12673 MB, largest block: 12673 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 4294065009 MB
    Total available memory: 4294080737 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 31 MB
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.2~git2406070600.db38a4~oibaf~n (git-db38a49 2024-06-07 noble-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.2~git2406070600.db38a4~oibaf~n (git-db38a49 2024-06-07 noble-oi
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.2~git2406070600.db38a4~oibaf~n (git-db38a49 2024-06-07 noble-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

5.inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-P GT2 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Luxvisions Innotech Integrated RGB Camera driver: uvcvideo
    type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: vesa dri: swrast gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: swrast platforms: x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: N/A renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6
    256 bits)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib


systeminfo

Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.10.0-rc2 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × Genuine Intel® 0000
Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: XXXXXXXX
System Version: ThinkPad L14 Gen 3

Really really thanks everyone who want to help me. :)

One more thing: if I use motrix to download something or use bluetooth connect to my earphone, after about 1-10min it will be surely freezed.

Please do not use comments to add info to the question. Edit the question and add the info.

That is not the kernel that Kubuntu 24.04 shipped with according to published info.

Thanks. As I say, I`ve tried the KUbuntu 6.8.1-31-genric and 6.8.1-35-genric, both of them runs abnormally. So I compolied 6.9.1 kernel and 6.10.1-rc2, but also both of them runs abnormally...

6.9 and 6.10 are not currently supported

emm... Does 6.8.1-35-generic or 6.8.1-31-generic not supported yet?
